# vim fugitive how to work on commit message while adding files?

Tags: vim, vim-fugitive

I have been using vim-fugitive which is great but I haven't figured out a good way to work on a commit message while I am adding files. My workflow has been like this...

```
:Gstatus
```

diff the files in a vsplit with

```
dv
```

look through the diff, go to another editor compose the message and then `git add` the file

```
-
```

repeat for all needed additions copy the composed message from my other editor and then

```
cc
```

and paste my commit message into fugitive's commit butter. I would like to develop a way to work on the commit message as I am going through and adding the files without having to get out of vim. What do you think is the best flow to accomplish this?

Comment: Fugitive provides `:Gcommit` (and bindings for it in `:Gstatus`). You can view files while editing a commit message from `git commit` as well, esp. if your `$EDITOR` is set to `vim`.